# Adding Subscription In-App Purchase to Safari Web Extension

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, subscription, safari-web-extension

I have created a Safari Web Extension, now I want to add Subscription In-App Purchase into this app.

Since the Safari Web Extension has two parts: the Mac App and the Extension.

I want to ask can I add the IAP codes into the Extension part?  So, the Extension can be programmatically enabled or disabled according to the latest subscription status.

Answer (score 1):

You can send conditions from macOS app to their safari extension javascript executing file via SFSafariApplication.dispatchMessage

Send Messages from the App to JavaScript **macOS**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/messaging_between_the_app_and_javascript_in_a_safari_web_extension

**but for iOS** there note
*"You can’t send messages from a containing iOS app to your web extension’s JavaScript scripts."*

So I'm looking solution right now how to end status ON/OFF to extension javascript file to toggle it depend on subscription status. It's strange how apple want us developers to monetize our extensions?

Comment: Have you contacted Apple support about this?

Comment: no, this is time waste and all it has I see already. The only way for me was to put the app as a paid. since for me, it was more experiment, so I go in this way. 

In my case, I did a youtube ad blocker extension where a javascript file did that.
https://apps.apple.com/us/app/youtube-ad-blocker/id1590323175

Initially, I thought to create an app group and share conditions with the extension but still, I have no access to the javascript file.

Comment: I think we need to file a feature request to Apple, so Apple will know we need this.

Comment: At this time it is still no solution?

Comment: This is why it was a poor decision for Apple to require native apps to install a browser extension and have to add needless communication back and forth to the native app. It's clearly just because Apple doesn't want to build a proper JS API for purchases (and of course we can't use our own payments system either because of the Apple tax). Super frustrating.